# Use variable in HELM template define function

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to use a variable inside the template define function? I attempted to wrap the variable in brackets but it seems to fail. Example

```
{{- define {{ .Chart.Name }}.deployment -}}
```

Comment: You need to provide full use-case and the error related to it that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

The names of template functions are always fixed strings.  (This is common with almost all programming languages.)  Since these names don't appear anywhere in the rendered YAML, it doesn't really matter what they're called.  The only place there's a potential conflict is if your chart includes other subcharts as dependencies, or is included as a subchart; in that case all template functions share the same function namespace.

A common convention is to name templates following the current chart name; that is, matching the fixed string in the `Chart.yaml` file

```
{{- define "mychart.deployment" -}}
```

Using the Helm `include` function you can *call* templates with a dynamic name, but this is a somewhat unusual use.

Answer (score 0):

**values.yaml**

```
global:
  key: {}
  deployment: appdeployv1
```

If you were to expand the name of the chart, you would do it like this

**_helpers.tpl**

```
{{- define "key.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.deployment | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

That's all I can understand from your question. I hope this helps. You can try exploring [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#:%7E:text=To%20work%20around%20this%20case,other%20functions%20in%20the%20pipeline.) and check **Declaring and using templates with define and template** heading for detailed info.